# How to get the username from form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I ran today into a special situation.  Previously I had the following in my view.py

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password2'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form})
    return render_to_response('registration/register.html', variables)
```

It was pretty straight forward retrieving the username, email and password to create a new user after she has registered.  But now I have refactored it to use a hash code as the username and utilize the email alone to register and login.

The shortened RegistrationForm looks like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"))
   password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
   password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput))

   class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)

   def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.username = md5(email).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

The new form doesn't have the username any longer, since it is calculated and not entered by the user any more.  But how do I retrieve the username from the view ?  The new code is not from me and I have it from a blog. Maybe the key is here in the Meta class?  From the documentation I wasn't able to fully understood what he is trying to achieve with the Meta class here...

Many Thanks,

**EDIT**:

Ok I think I understand now how the subclassing should work. I tried to subclass the User class like this:

```
class cb_user_model_backend(ModelBackend):

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password only.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        username = md5(email).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
            is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
            last_login=now, date_joined=now)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

The problem I am facing now are two errors, self._db and self.model, were meant to be on the base user class. How do get to them from here?

**Edit 2:**

PyCharm complains that the two self._db and seld.model don't exit on current cb_user_model_backend.

Note the View is refactored to take two parameters:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
                password=form.cleaned_data['password2'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
```

When running it stack trace is:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
create_user() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: It would be fair to write a comment why somebody would down vote a valid question. Very constructive!

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing your save method in your models.py:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.username = md5(self.email).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

After calling user.save(), user.username should yield the generated username in your views. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
If you want to call create_user(**kwargs), you could do the following in your views.py:

```
email = self.cleaned_data['email']
username = md5(email).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
u = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email, password = password)
```

Comment: But when creating a user object User.objects.create_user(...) I still need a username to pass as parameter, no?

Comment: @Kave yes you do. You could subclass create_user the way I subclassed save to automatically generate a username the way you do with md5. Or you could do what I posted in my edit.

Comment: yeah you are right I could just refactor it from forms into the view. But I was also trying the subclass idea and created one, with two minor problems.  Please see Edit. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, @Kave?